# Reset styling on radio and checkboxes but leave other input styles

Tags: html, css

Creating a couple forms and I have styled the text inputs and textareas the way I would like them to look. I am now getting to the radio buttons and checkboxes and they have naturally inherited the style of the other inputs.

Is there a way to reset this and put them back to default styling? I've never really run into this problem. Looking for only css or html solution.

Here is a picture of what is happening : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivvmB.jpg

Here is my relevant css

```
/* style drop down box */
#panel_body select {
    width:243px;
    height:40px;
    border:1px solid #9b9b9b;
    border-radius:8px;
}

/* style input elements */
#panel_body input, #panel_body textarea {
    width:243px;
    height:40px;
    border:1px solid #9b9b9b;
    border-radius:8px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #adadad);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #adadad);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #adadad);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #adadad);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #adadad);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0,
 StartColorStr='#FFffff', EndColorStr='#adadad');

}

/* style textareas */
#panel_body textarea {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    height:100px;
    padding:5px;
    font-family: Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
}

/* input elements hover and select state */
#panel_body input:hover, #panel_body textarea:hover,  
#panel_body input:focus, #panel_body textarea:focus {  
    border-color: #025389;  
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 0px 0px 8px;  
    }
```

Comment: "looking for only css or html solution" - cool library anyway though, so thanks for that

Comment: Right. My bad. I don't think there is one.

Comment: Use more specific selectors on your inputs so your checkboxes and radios don't inherit styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox] {
    // Reset attributes here
}
```

Or use a more specific selector than just `input` in the rest of your CSS.

Comment: @thisuser Technically, this won't restore it to the browser's defaults.  It will only restyle it.

Comment: Yea, I added the specific selector to the rest of my CSS. Should have mentioned that. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

If you want to style all inputs *except* checkbox and radio, you would use this selector:

```
input:not([type="checkbox"]):not([type="radio"])
```

http://jsfiddle.net/29CTy/

I believe you'll find that there's other input types that you'll want to leave in their unstyled state as well (particularly the `date` and `time` collection).  Personally, I style only the *texty* type inputs as that list is typically shorter than the list of types I would prefer to leave unstyled:

```
input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="search"], input[type="email"], input[type="tel"], input[type="url"]
```

Answer (score 0):

use `#panel_body input[type="text"],#panel_body textarea` for add css on textbox and textarea

And use `input[type="radio"]` and `input[type="checkbox"]` for add css on  checkbox and radio button.